# Product of matrices of a linear operator and of its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

Why if a linear operator $\phi$ is an isomorphism and we multiply the matrices of $\phi$ and of $\phi^{-1}$ in any basis, the result is $E$ the matrix that has $1$ on the diagonal and everything else is $0$.

Comment: Because for any basis $\;\{u_1,...\}\;$ of a vector space, $\;\text{Id.}\,x_i=1\cdot x_i\;,\;\;\forall\,i\;$

Comment: What does multiplication mean here? $\phi(x), \phi^{-1}(x)$ are elements of a vector space?

Comment: @Timbuc what id means?

Comment: @Karlo Identity map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $M_{WV}(\phi)$ of a linear transformation $\phi:E\to F$ in bases $V$ of $E$ and $W$ of $F$ is defined such that 
$$[\phi(x)]_W=M_{WV}(\phi)\cdot[x]_V$$ where $[x]_W$ denotes the coordinates of $x$ is the basis $V$, and $[\phi(x)]_W$ the coordinates of $\phi(x)$ in $W$.

Then $$I\cdot[x]_W=[x]_W=[\phi\circ \phi^{-1}(x)]_W=M_{WV}(\phi)\cdot[\phi^{-1}(x)]_V=M_{WV}\cdot(\phi)M_{VW}(\phi^{-1})\cdot[x]_W$$
for all $x$. Therefore

$$I=M_{WV}(\phi)\cdot M_{VW}(\phi^{-1}).$$

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out $\phi(x)$=Basis.Matrix.Cordinates,let the matrices be A and B,however we have the equality $\phi(x).\phi^{-1}(y)$=$yx$ then A.B=1 and q.e.d?

Comment: It is very unclear what you are doing there. If you ask me, I think nothing is getting proven there.

Comment: let $x=x_1e_1+x_2e_2 .....x_ne_n$ ,then $\phi(x)$=row$(e_1,e_2..e_n).M$.col($x_1,x_2.....x_n$),where M is some matrix.Now if we apply this in our equality and replace the variables respectively (we put on M A and then on the other operator B) we divide by the basis on square and $x_i$ and $y_i$ we are left that matrix(A).matrix(B)=1 and this ends it

Comment: the equation is $row(e_1,e_2 ...e_n).A.col(x_1,x_2...x_n).row(e_1,e_2 ...e_n).B.col(y_1,y_2...y_n) = col(x_1...x_n)(y_1...y_n)$